# MSMQ Requirements for Rebus

Tags: msmq, rebus

I'm starting out using Rebus with MSMQ, but I cannot seem to find the requirements for MSMQ.

So in the (Roles|Programs and Features) which options do I need to set and what is the impact wrt to Rebus?

I'm pretty sure I need the `Message Queuing Server` ;-) But what about the others:

- Directory Service Integration
- HTTP Support
- Message Queuing Triggers
- Multicast Support
- Routing Service

I think none of these are needed and none of the extra features are supported by Rebus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll ruin anything by checking one or more of those extra options, but the only requirement for Rebus to work is that you put a single checkmark in the top level Message Queueing Server.

You're absolutely right that I ought to document this on the wiki - it's almost too easy :)